# What plugin does Stack Overflow use for "Was this post useful to you?"

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which tools and technologies build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

When not logged in Stack Overflow shows this message

> "Was this post useful to you?"

I was wondering if anybody could tell me what plugin does Stack Overflow use to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: Why would it be using a plugin?

Comment: Hey Bart ! I am not sure.., just thought it would be using a plugin as there are many jquery feedback plugin that offer the similar kind of functionality.

Comment: @Bart you really think this [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network) has the answer ?? how can this be a dupe ?

Comment: I strongly suspect this was custom written, and no jQuery plugin was used. The effect is not *that* special to build - it's a simple `.show()` with a fade, isn't it?

Comment: It informs about all the tools and technologies used to develop the site. So one of them is most likely your answer. And as Pekka says, I suspect it's simply custom developed functionality.

Comment: I agree with @pek - All I can see is is a hover event triggering a fade in animation... Not really something you would *need* a plugin to do...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's using plain AJAX, no plugin. It boils down to this code executed upon clicking a feedback button: (`b` is the post ID)

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/vote/anon/" + b,
    data: {
        votetypeid: "Yes" == a.val() ? 2 : 3
    },
    complete: function () {}
})
```